# Need regex help: Match if certain string doesn't start with certain sub-patterns AND certain character should not be there

Tags: python, regex

I need to come up with a regular expression for a mini-project.

The string should not start with:

```
"/wiki"
```

and it should also not have the following pattern
`"/.*:.*"`    (basically pattern starts with char '/' and there is any occurrence of ':' after that)

and it also cannot have a certain character `'#'`

So basically all these strings would fail:

```
"/wiki/index.php?title=ROM/TAP&amp;action=edit&amp;section=2"
"/User:romamns"
"/Special:Watchlist"
"/Space_Wiki:Privacy_policy"
"#column-one"
```

And all these string would pass:

```
"/ROM/TAP/mouse"
"http://www.boost.org/"
```

I will be using the regex in python (if that makes any difference).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^(/(?!wiki)[^:#]*|[^#/][^#]*)$` should be ok, as tested [here](http://re-try.appspot.com/), of course I might be missing something, but this appears to follow your specification.

Comment: Works great, Thank you sir. I have been struggling with this since a couple of hours.

Comment: what in the world is the purpose of `{1}`?

Comment: Yeah, redundant `{1}` was redundat. Also: glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

This tested script implements a commented regex which precisely matches your stated requirements:

```py
import re
def check_str(subject):
    """Retturn True if subject matches"""

    reobj = re.compile(
        """               # Match special string
        (?!/wiki)         # Does not start with /wiki.
        (?![^/]*/[^:]*:)  # Does not have : following /
        [^#]*             # Match whole string having no #
        $                 # Anchor to end of string.
        """, 
        re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
    if reobj.match(subject):
        return True
    else:
        return False
        return False

data_list = [
    r"/wiki/index.php?title=ROM/TAP&amp;action=edit&amp;section=2",
    r"/User:romamns",
    r"/Special:Watchlist",
    r"/Space_Wiki:Privacy_policy",
    r"#column-one",
    r"/ROM/TAP/mouse",
    r"http://www.boost.org/",
    ]
cnt = 0
for data in data_list:
    cnt += 1
    print("Data[%d] = \"%s\"" %
      (cnt, check_str(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you match the following regular expression, then it should fail

```
^(\/wiki|.*?[\:#])
```